# Updating global variable value REACT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The function 'clicknode' seems to successfully update the variable 'selected' as desired but when I try to access the variable from another function it still shows as empty.

```
  let selected=[]

  const clickNode = (id) => {
    console.log(`${id} clicked!`);
    if(selected.includes(id)){
      for(let i=0;i<selected.length;i++){
        if(selected[i]===id){
          selected.splice(i,1);}
      }
    }
    else{ selected.push(id)}
    console.log(selected);
  }
```

Comment: Where do you try to access it in another function? Provide a [mcve]. Make it a [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)

Comment: (The answer will almost certainly come down to "Use state, that is what it is for")